# Can Boltzmann transport equation as implemented in Boltztrap software be considered first-principles?

Tags: electronic-transport, transport, boltztrap

According to the documentation of [Boltztrap](https://boltztrap2y.readthedocs.io/en/latest/psuwork.html#electrical-conductivity), the electrical conductivity is given in the following equation: $$\sigma=\frac{1}{k_BT}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f(1-f)\mathrm{\textbf{X}}(\varepsilon)d\varepsilon\tag{1}$$

where $\mathrm{\textbf{X}}$ is the transport distribution function: $$X^{\alpha\beta}(\varepsilon)=\frac{e^2}{V}\int_{}^{}\sum_{i}^{}{v}_{i}^{\alpha}(\textbf{K}){v}_{i}^{\beta}(\textbf{K})\tau_{i,k}\delta(\varepsilon-\varepsilon_i(\textbf{K}))\frac{d\textbf{K}}{8\pi^3}\tag{2}$$

Where *e* is the electric charge, *V* is the volume, $\tau_{i,k}$ is the relaxation time, and ${v}_{i}^{\alpha}(\textbf{K})$ is the electron group velocity.

**can we consider the calculation of the electrical conductivity according to the above equation in softwares like Boltztrap which as I understand is an implementation of the Boltzmann transport equation to be first-principles?**

Comment: +1 but please add equation numbers.